# Popup wont open upon JQuery Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't get changeuserjudge.php to open. I've put it in several other places without any success whatsoever. Can anyone tell me why this is?

JQuery:

```
    $('#userCreateSave').click(function(){
                var success = false;    
                var createUserName = $('#createUserName').val();
                var createUserEmail = $('#createUserEmail').val();
                var createUserType = $('#createUserType').val();
                if (jQuery.trim($('#createUserEmail').val()).length<1){
                    alert ("Please enter an email address.");
                    return false;
                }
                else {

                    $.ajax({   
                            type: "POST",   
                            url: "adminmenu.php",   
                            data: 'createUserName=' + createUserName + '&createUserEmail=' + createUserEmail+ '&createUserType=' + createUserType,
                            success: function(){
                                success = true;
                                $('#newCreateRow').remove();
                                $('#tableUsers tr:first').after('<tr class="altr"><td>-</td><td>'+createUserName+'</td><td>'+createUserEmail+'</td><td>'+createUserType+'</td><td>Active</td></tr>');
                                $('#newUserLink').show();
                            }

                        }); 
                }
                    if(success) {
                       window.open("changeuserjudge.php"); 
                    }
            });
```

Comment: Are you sure AJAX "Success" event is firing and "success" is actually being set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting a boolean called `success`, create a function called `success()`, and execute it once the request has finished. Your code doesn't work as intended, because `success` is false immediately after the `$.ajax()` call.

Execution model:

> `.ajax()`
>   `success == false`
>   AJAX finished: set `success = true`
>   *End of function*

A possible implementation:

```
var success = function(){
   window.open("changeuserjudge.php"); 
}
$.ajax({   
        type: "POST",   
        url: "adminmenu.php",   
        data: 'createUserName=' + createUserName + '&createUserEmail=' + createUserEmail+ '&createUserType=' + createUserType,
        success: function(){
            success(); //Execute the callback function: `success()`
            $('#newCreateRow').remove();
            $('#tableUsers tr:first').after('<tr class="altr"><td>-</td><td>'+createUserName+'</td><td>'+createUserEmail+'</td><td>'+createUserType+'</td><td>Active</td></tr>');
            $('#newUserLink').show();
        }

    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't you put the open within your success function. thereby making sure to call it when the ajax call is completed. it won't be setting it to true because ajax is asynchronous

Answer (score 2):

the first a in ajax means asynchronous, meaning the success callback gets called out of the normal flow and thus after the `if(success)` statement. you should put the `window.open("changeuserjudge.php");` inside the success callback.

Answer (score 1):

you should include

```
window.open("changeuserjudge.php");
```

within the sucess callback function , also make sure to log to see wether the sucess function is executed or not

```
console.log("success")
```

the local variable success you created has nothing to do with the option sucess , it's always gonna be false .